# Chrome script to auto highlight a user defined set of keywords

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Are there any Chrome scripts or extensions out there that can automatically highlight a user predefined set of keywords and phrases?  I've searched around and had no luck.  Seems that there are Firefox add-ons that will do what I'm looking for (Vocabulary Highlighter), but nothing for Chrome so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about any existing extensions.

If you wanted to make one, you would just need to write an extension with a javascript regular expression that is inserted as a content script and adds a bit of css to any matches.

Answer (score 0):

Found 3 similar extensions for Google Chrome:

- [Keywords Highlighter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keywords-highlighter/nnfnbecknbhnihnjjbblckanjajgjkkh?hl=en)
- [MultiHighlighter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multihighlighter/ocifbglmlbpgpbflnkfpclkmckoollbn?hl=en)
- [word highlight](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/word-highlight/ooabkmkhabkahcjbgpiajffckeibpdoa?hl=en)

The third one doesn't work very well from what I've tried, but I included it anyway.
I think the first two should be what you are looking for.